# How to fix "Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans' while adding text on image using react-native-ffmpeg

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I am trying to add text on image using the code below
RNFFmpeg
.execute(`` `-y -i ${input} -vf "drawtext=text='Hello World':fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=0:y=0" ${output}` ``);

I am not using any custom font but still get this error.

**Error:**

[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7f87a1ce40] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans

index.js:115 [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f6765e760] Error initializing filter 'drawtext'
index.js:115 [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f6765e760] with args 'text=Hello World:fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=0:y=0'
index.js:115 [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f6765e760]

index.js:115 Error reinitializing filters!

index.js:115 Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory

index.js:115 Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

**Note:**

I also tried using a custom font but not able to do it.
When I use RNFFmpegConfig.setFontDirectory('../../assets/fonts') function and with it the following code to add text on image
RNFFmpeg
.execute(`` `-y -i ${input} -vf "drawtext=text='Hello World':fontfile='../../assets/fonts/MyFont.ttf':fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=0:y=0" ${output}` ``);

It gives me the same error.

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Does the same command work if you run the plain command, with no react or javascript, in a terminal?

Comment: @llogan yes it worked from terminal

Comment: Probably not a problem with ffmpeg itself then. Does this react stuff have permission to access the fonts?

Comment: I am using  react-native-ffmpeg library I have read the document, how to I give permissions I am unable to find it, please help?

Answer (score 0):

according to this
https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Tips

you should registering the fonts under a directory using the `FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectory` methods or by specifying your own fontconfig configuration using `FFmpegKitConfig.setFontconfigConfigurationPath`

System fonts on Android are stored under the `/system/fonts folder`
and on iOS are stored under the `/System/Library/Fonts`